# Compile in Java was fine, but running causes errors

Tags: java, runtime-error

Okay, so I did javac dicebot.java, it worked fine, but when I did java dicebot.java I got this:
I really do not know how much better I can explain it considering I have no clue what these errors that I got mean. So any help would be great, Thank you!

It is different than that question that you stated there because it has nothing to do with it. This is a completely different question and it's errors are unique...

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1086)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:966)
at dicebot.<init>(dicebot.java:67)
at dicebot$1.run(dicebot.java:26)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Here is my coding that I made and tried to run:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class dicebot extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    public static JComboBox combo;
    public static JButton btnConfirm;
    public static JTextField txtUserName;
    public static JTextField txtStartBid;
    public static JTextField txtMultiplier;
    public static JTextField txtMinRemaining;
    public static JTextField txtPassword;
    public static JTextField txtOdds;
    public static JTextField txtMaxBet;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    dicebot frame = new dicebot();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public dicebot() {
        setTitle("Dice Bot");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0};
        gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);

        //Every new Label however needs every part that says "user" or on the Password: "pass" changed to something unique.
        JLabel userTag = new JLabel("Username:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_userTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_userTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_userTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_userTag.gridx = 0;//Here are your x + y coords
        gbc_userTag.gridy = 0;//Adding to x moves left, adding to y moves down
        panel.add(userTag, gbc_userTag);

        //Every new textfield needs only the * part to change for it to be valid. (gbc_* =)
        txtUserName = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints txtUserName = new GridBagConstraints();
        txtUserName.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        txtUserName.gridx = 1;
        txtUserName.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(textField,txtUserName);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel startTag = new JLabel("Starting Bid:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_startTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_startTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_startTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_startTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_startTag.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(startTag, gbc_startTag);

        txtStartBid = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints txtStartBid = new GridBagConstraints();
        txtStartBid.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        txtStartBid.gridx = 1;
        txtStartBid.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(textField, txtStartBid);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel multTag = new JLabel("Multiplier:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_multTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_multTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_multTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_multTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_multTag.gridy = 3;
        panel.add(multTag, gbc_multTag);

        txtMultiplier = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints txtMultiplier = new GridBagConstraints();
        txtMultiplier.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        txtMultiplier.gridx = 1;
        txtMultiplier.gridy = 3;
        panel.add(textField, txtMultiplier);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel minTag = new JLabel("Min Remaining:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_minTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_minTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_minTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_minTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_minTag.gridy = 4;
        panel.add(minTag, gbc_minTag);

        txtMinRemaining = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints txtMinRemaining = new GridBagConstraints();
        txtMinRemaining.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        txtMinRemaining.gridx = 1;
        txtMinRemaining.gridy = 4;
        panel.add(textField, txtMinRemaining);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        txtPassword = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints txtPassword = new GridBagConstraints();
        txtPassword.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        txtPassword.gridx = 1;
        txtPassword.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(textField, txtPassword);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel passTag = new JLabel("Password:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_passTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_passTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_passTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_passTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_passTag.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(passTag, gbc_passTag);

        txtOdds = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints txtOdds = new GridBagConstraints();
        txtOdds.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        txtOdds.gridx = 1;
        txtOdds.gridy = 5;
        panel.add(textField, txtOdds);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JLabel oddsTag = new JLabel("Odds %:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_oddsTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_oddsTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_oddsTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_oddsTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_oddsTag.gridy = 5;
        panel.add(oddsTag, gbc_oddsTag);

        txtMaxBet = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints txtMaxBet = new GridBagConstraints();
        txtMaxBet.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        txtMaxBet.gridx = 1;
        txtMaxBet.gridy = 6;
        panel.add(textField, txtMaxBet);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        //This is the Combo Box
        combo = new JComboBox<String>(new String[]{"BTC","LTC","PPC","NMC","XPM","FTC","ANC","DOGE","NXT"});
        combo.addActionListener(this);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_list = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_list.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_list.gridx = 1;
        gbc_list.gridy = 7;
        panel.add(combo, gbc_list);

        JLabel maxTag = new JLabel("MaxBet:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_maxTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_maxTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_maxTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_maxTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_maxTag.gridy = 6;
        panel.add(maxTag, gbc_maxTag);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel_1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 5, 5));

        btnConfirm = new JButton("Turn Up");
    btnConfirm.addActionListener(this);
    panel_1.add(btnConfirm);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Current Balance");
        textArea.setColumns(1);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);

    JScrollPane scrollPanel1 = new JScrollPane();//This will hold the information the bot sends over such as win/loose or error
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JTextArea textAreal = new JTextArea("Input bot information here...");
        textArea.setColumns(20);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);

        pack();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == combo) {
            System.out.println(combo.getSelectedIndex()+1);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line is line 67?

Comment: so you ask us to understand code that's not written by you and fix it for you, but you don't even tell us which is line 67 where the exception is thrown?

Comment: I wrote this code myself?
Line 67:panel.add(textField,txtUserName);

Comment: you are talking about "decompilation" which is the opposite of "compilation".

Comment: I mean when I do javac in command line... oh I see, I titled it decompile...

Comment: **WHICH LINE IS LINE 67????**

Comment: Line 67:panel.add(textField,txtUserName);

Comment: There -- was that so hard?

Comment: I said it above, 4 minutes ago...

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) - learn it, know it, live it!

Comment: Jarrod, this question is completely unique because it involves a completely different code and error list. I'm sorry if I just started learning java but, answers to a code that is different than mine does not help that much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `NullPointerException` means that something is trying to call a method or access a variable of an object which is `null`.

According to your comment the exception is thrown at

```
panel.add(textField,txtUserName);
```

Now, `txtUserName` is initialized few lines before so it shouldn't be the cause, what about `textField` variable?

Comment: So, get rid of the textField variable?

Comment: You simply never set the `textField` variable, give it a value first.

Answer (score 0):

As Jack pointed out, `textField` is not initialized.

Comment: How do I fix that? I'm really confused...

Comment: The same way as you did for the other fields: `textField = new JTextField();`

Comment: Is that in place of txtUserName = new JTextField();?